# Multiple constructors on an immutable (data) class

Tags: constructor, kotlin, immutability, data-class

I'm trying to implement an immutable data class with more than one constructor. I felt that something like this should be possible:

```
data class Color(val r: Int, val g: Int, val b: Int) {
   constructor(hex: String) {
        assert(Regex("#[a-fA-F0-6]{6}").matches(hex), { "$hex is not a hex color" } )
        val r = hex.substring(1..2).toInt(16)
        val g = hex.substring(3..4).toInt(16)
        val b = hex.substring(5..6).toInt(16)
        this(r,g,b)
    }
}
```

Of course, it isn't: Kotlin expects the call to the main constructor be declared at the top:

```
constructor(hex: String): this(r,g,b) {
    assert(Regex("#[a-fA-F0-6]{6}").matches(hex), { "$hex is not a hex color" } )
    val r = hex.substring(1..2).toInt(16)
    val g = hex.substring(3..4).toInt(16)
    val b = hex.substring(5..6).toInt(16)
}
```

That's no good either, as the call is executed *before* the constructor body and can not access the local variables.

I can do *this*, of course:

```
constructor(hex: String): this(hex.substring(1..2).toInt(16),
                               hex.substring(3..4).toInt(16), 
                               hex.substring(5..6).toInt(16)) {
    assert(Regex("#[a-fA-F0-6]{6}").matches(hex), { "$hex is not a hex color" } )
}
```

But this will check the assertion too late, and does not scale very well.

The only way I see to get close to the desired behaviour is this using a  helper function (which can't be defined non-static on `Color`):

```
constructor(hex: String): this(hexExtract(hex, 1..2), 
                               hexExtract(hex, 3..4), 
                               hexExtract(hex, 5..6))
```

This does not strike me as a very elegant pattern, so I'm guessing I'm missing something here.

Is there an elegant, idiomatic way to have (complex) secondary constructors on immutable data classes in Kotlin?

Comment: An alternative: Use a factory method instead in a companion object.

Comment: @nhaarman I didn't come all the way from Java to use factories... :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/generic-object-creation/1663/5), using the operator function `invoke` on the companion object (just like Scala's `apply`) one can achieve not really a constructor, but a factory that *looks* like a constructor usage-site:

```
companion object {
    operator fun invoke(hex: String) : Color {
        assert(Regex("#[a-fA-F0-6]{6}").matches(hex),
               {"$hex is not a hex color"})
        val r = hex.substring(1..2).toInt(16)
        val g = hex.substring(3..4).toInt(16)
        val b = hex.substring(5..6).toInt(16)
        return Color(r, g, b)
    }
}
```

Now, `Color("#FF00FF")` will to the expected thing.

Comment: I think we have a winner

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by @nhaarman, one way to is use a factory method. I often use something like the following:

```
data class Color(val r: Int, val g: Int, val b: Int) {
   companion object {
        fun fromHex(hex: String): Color {
            assert(Regex("#[a-fA-F0-6]{6}").matches(hex), { "$hex is not a hex color" } )
            val r = hex.substring(1..2).toInt(16)
            val g = hex.substring(3..4).toInt(16)
            val b = hex.substring(5..6).toInt(16)
            return Color(r,g,b)
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can call it with `Color.fromHex("#abc123")`

Comment: Poor-man constructors -- I'd hoped that Kotlin moved beyond that.

Comment: @Raphael Why do you think they are so bad? I find them very useful.

Comment: They're actually cleaner than constructors, IMHO. When you see `Color.fromHex(s)`, it's immediately clear what the line does, and what `s` is supposed to be. When you see `Color(s)`, you have no idea.

Comment: @Raphael I agree with @jb-nizet, at least for this particular example. `Color.fromHex(...)` more clearly expresses the intent. It also makes it possible to have methods that would otherwise be colliding with just a constructor, e.g. `Color.fromCmyk(...)` (or whatever -- I don't know anything about color spaces)

Comment: @JBNizet That's what documentation is for. I've been writing some Swift lately, and initializers are a lot better there (in particular, they can be required by protocols, which is something I'm missing already). External parameter labels help a lot with readability, I guess; you *could* write `Color(hex = s)` in Kotlin!

Comment: @ean5533 True, multiple constructors using the same parameter types are impossible in Java. Doesn't mean they necessarily have to be in Kotlin, but it appears it inherited that particular weakness.

Comment: That said, even *Java* can do what I originally want: write an additional constructor that computes and sets the members of the object. Why does it even have to call the default constructor?

Comment: FYI: It's possible to make factories *look* like constructors; see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43128459/539599).