# How to apply function to value defined in data class constructor before init method?

Tags: constructor, kotlin, invariants, data-class

Let's say I have a data class like this:

```
data class MyData(val something: Int, val somethingElse : String) {
    init {
        require(something > 20) { "Something must be > 20" }
        require(StringUtils.isNotEmtpy(somethingElse)) { "Something else cannot be blank" }
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to apply a function to `somethingElse` before the `init` method is called. In this case I want to remove all `\n` characters from the `somethingElse` String while maintaining immutability of the field (i.e. `somethingElse` must still be a `val`). I'd like to do something similar to this in Java:

```
public class MyData {

    private final int something;
    private final String somethingElse;

    public MyDate(int something, String somethingElse) {
        this.something = something;
        this.somethingElse = StringUtils.replace(somethingElse, '\n', '');

        Validate.isTrue(something > 20, "...");
        Validate.isTrue(StringUtils.isNotEmtpy(this.somethingElse), "...");
    }

    // Getters
}
```

I could of course create a normal class (i.e. no data class) in Kotlin but I want `MyData` to be a data class.

What is the idiomatic way to do this in Kotlin?

Comment: You won't be able to do this, see some of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44435419/4465208

Comment: What is wrong with:
    `require(StringUtils.isNotEmtpy(somethingElse.replace("\n", ""))) { "Something else cannot be blank" }`

Comment: @mTak OP also wants the field to have the cleaned-up value.

Comment: @jingx it's a val field, if both values are needed then the cleaned value must be stored separately.

Comment: Another guy tried hard to achieve it, asked for help in his [blog post](http://gopalkri.com/2017/08/18/Kotlin-Data-Class-Constructor-Problem-Followup/) and eventually had to write out everything in long-hand.

Comment: @mTak right, that's why the commenter before you responded that it's impossible with a plain vanilla data class.

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43030408/539599).

Answer (score 2):

While you can not *literally* do what you want, you can fake it.

- Make all constructors of your data class private.
- Implement factories/builders/whatevers on the companion as `operator fun invoke`.

Usages of `Companion.invoke` will -- in Kotlin! -- look just like constructor calls.

In your example:

```
data class MyData private constructor(
    val something: Int, 
    val somethingElse : String
) {
    init {
        require(something > 20) { "Something must be > 20" }
        require("" != somethingElse) { "Something else cannot be blank" }
    }

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(something: Int, somethingElse: String) : MyData =
            MyData(something, somethingElse.replace("\n", " "))
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val m = MyData(77, "something\nwicked\nthis\nway\ncomes")
    println(m.somethingElse)
}
```

Prints:

> something wicked this way comes

You'll note the helpful warning:

> Private data class constructor is exposed via the generated 'copy' method.

This method can not be overridden (as far as I can tell) so you have to take care, still. One solution is to hide the actual data class away:

```
interface MyData {
    val s: Int
    val sE: String

    private data class MyDataImpl(
        override val s: Int,
        override val sE: String
    ) : MyData {
        init {
            require(s > 20) { "Something must be > 20" }
            require("" != sE) { "Something else cannot be blank" }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(s: Int, sE: String) : MyData =
                MyDataI(s, sE.replace("\n", " "))
    }
}
```

Now your invariant (no line breaks) is maintained, `copy` and other dangerous methods (if any, I haven't checked) are hidden away -- but therefore also unavailable, potentially removing some of the convenience data classes provide.

Choose your poison.